# EntityDataSource, QueryCreated, and DropDownLists

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a drop down list (ddlFilterBuildings) which contains a list of buildings to choose from.

I have an EntityDataSource and a Sub that triggers on QueryCreated. It is as follows:

```
    Protected Sub EntityDataSource1_QueryCreated(sender As Object, e As QueryCreatedEventArgs)
      Dim residents = e.Query.Cast(Of Resident)()
      e.Query = From p In residents _
                Where p.building = ddlFilterBuildings.SelectedValue
    End Sub
```

This works great. It filters by whatever building is selected in the drop down list...but now a problem. Sometimes folks want to see all of the buildings - not just one. I attempted to add a null value which I hoped would select all - but this doesn't seem to work. So, now my dropdownlist in addition to the databound options includes:

```
    ddlFilterBuildings.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select Building --")
    ddlFilterBuildings.Items(0).Value = vbNull
```

But this just shows no rows in the table...and if I change to a specific building it doesn't change either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I am getting from the question, the table only gets populated in that QueryCreated Sub Routine.  Try Updating the table in the drop down list's [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event.

Comment: How can I force the table to update? Calling a DataBind on the GridView?

Comment: I'll answer my own question. Yes, by calling DataBind on the GridView. :)